# Take control over robots.txt and sitemap.xml

Tags: shopify

Is it possible, either through some settings or through developing a app to take control over robots.txt and sitemap.xml for a shopify store?

I've tried setting up a url redirect but it seems that these pre-generated files are used before url direction happens. Is there anyway an app could get around this?

Looking over the api it doesn't seem likely, but I thought I'd check here before abandoning the idea. Right now the only solution I can think of is buying a separate domain name that would be the front of the store, and then using mod_rewrite to essentially proxy all urls that aren't robots.txt and the sitemap xmls to the store.shopify.com urls.

Will that solution fail?

I know it's probably not super efficient but from a primitive understanding I think it might work. I imagine there's no way to have all the links on the subdomain store point to the main domain store when it's not linked through dns, but that would be a smaller issue than having the default sitemap.

Answer (score 3):

These files are auto-generated by Shopify and cannot be overridden.

Comment: will this is enough  https://www.banglewale.com/sitemap.xml ?